# Identification of SMD marking which looks like a "P" and a "c"

Tags: identification, surface-mount

What is this SMD marking? I haven't been able to find it.

[image]

Comment: Looks very much like fuse. Probably resettable polyfuse? (because P?).

Comment: +1 for polyfuse.  It has the characteristic notches on the ends.